# Creating Haxe extern, return types

Tags: haxe, kineticjs

I'm trying to make an extern of KineticJS for Haxe. And I'm making the 'Transform' class, I'm missing a few pieces though.

```
extern class Transform {
    public function new();
    public function translate(x:Float, y:Float):Void;
    public function scale(sx:Float, sy:Float):Void;
    public function rotate(rad:Float):Void;

    /**
     * Returns the translation
     * @returns {Object} 2D point(x, y)
     */
    getTranslation: function() {
        return {
            x: this.m[4],
            y: this.m[5]
        };
    },

    public function multiply(matrix:Transform):Void;
    public function invert():Void;
    
    /**
     * return matrix
     */
    getMatrix: function() {
        return this.m;
    }
}
```

So, as you can see I'm missing `getTranslation` and `getMatrix`. This is because I'm not sure what their return type should be.

For those wondering, the `m` variable is defined as follows:

```
Kinetic.Transform = function() {
    this.m = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given `m` is storing a matrix, it should be an `Array<Float>`.

The return type of getTranslation is a [structure](http://haxe.org/manual/struct).

So at the end the functions should be:

```
public function getMatrix():Array<Float>;

public function getTranslation():{ x:Float, y:Float };
```